# reportserver a alternative to openreports?

Tags: open-source, business-intelligence

Uses or knows anyone ReportServer (http://sourceforge.net/projects/dw-rs/)? Who can tell me their experiences?

At first glance it looks like an alternative for OpenReports(http://sourceforge.net/projects/oreports/). But I am surprised that I have never heard from ReportServer.

The background of my question is the fact that is OpenReports no longer developed.
Currently, we use OpenReports with more than 150 reports (queries, jaspers and birt reports). Our desire is to migrate all reports in a new open source solution.

The problem is: We do not want to re-implement our reports.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReportServer is a relatively new project and thus not yet widely used. However, we (I am part of the ReportServer development team) are working on getting the message out there :D.

We used to run OpenReports with our customers but at a certain point faced the same decision. Back then (2009) we did not like the alternatives, partly because non were truly open source
but mostly because we liked the "OpenReports-idea" of a platform that is able to use the best of all solutions: OpenReports allows to, for example, use JasperReports as well as Birt reports, and furthermore has a very easy interface to just run simple queries.

After three years of intensive development we have recently released version 2.0. By now, we have also successfully ported allo our old OpenReports installations to ReportServer and are currently planning on publishing the necessary scripts to have this process as painless as possible. Have a look at http://blog.datenwerke.net for updates on this.

If you have any specific questions I would be glad to help you. Of course, I am biased in my opinion, but if you are looking for a modern and open BI solution (ReportServer is entirely open source) that allows to run Jasper as well as Birt and has very good Excel support, then you should definitely take a closer look at ReportServer.